# Fetching data deom Firestore in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have data like below in Firestore, I want to fetch that data. I am getting data in **List of QueryDocumentSnapshot** object. I want data in ArrayList.

```
{orderedItemsList:[
0={itemDescription:"These popular street dumplings are so versatile. You just need to master the technique and you can twist them to suit your palate.",
itemId:null,
itemImageURL:"https://www.ndtv.com/cooks/images/momos%20%281%29.jpg",
itemPrice:"40",
itemQuantity:12,
itemStatus:0,
itemTitle:"Veg Momos"
},
1:{itemDescription:"Who doesn't love burgers? Aloo Tikki Burger is loved by people of all age groups. This Fusion appetizer is made using simple ingredients like veg mayonnaise, burger bun, fried aloo tikki, sliced onions and tomatoes.".
itemId:null,
itemImageURL:"https://recipes.timesofindia.com/photo/62068349.cms?imgsize=342277",
itemPrice:"79",
itemQuantity:5,
itemStatus:0,
itemTitle:"Aloo Tikki Burger"}],
userEmail:"roshannimje94@gmail.com"}
```

Comment: look at here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46706433/firebase-firestore-get-data-from-collection

Comment: Thansk @GowthamanM, but I have extra value **userEmail**

Comment: can you post your quary code

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of you database to see it more clealy and also indicate which data you want to get. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    private List<Parties> newsList = new ArrayList<>();


   db.collection("dbref").orderBy("name", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).addSnapshotListener(this,new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
             @Override
             public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                 for (DocumentChange doc: documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){
                     String id = doc.getDocument().getId();
                     NewsFeed news = doc.getDocument().toObject(NewsFeed.class).withId(id);
                     switch (doc.getType()) {
                         case ADDED:
                             newsList.add(news);
                             mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                             break;
                         case MODIFIED:
                             newsList.remove(news);
                             newsList.add(news);
                             mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                             break;
                         case REMOVED:
                             newsList.remove(news);
                             mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                             break;
                     }
                 }

             }
         });
```

Pojo Would be

```
public class NewsFeed {


    String userEmail,itemTitle,itemDescription,itemId,itemPrice,itemImageURL,
            itemQuantity,itemStatus;

    public NewsFeed(String userEmail, String itemTitle, String itemDescription, String itemId, String itemPrice, String itemImageURL) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
        this.itemTitle = itemTitle;
        this.itemDescription = itemDescription;
        this.itemId = itemId;
        this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
        this.itemImageURL = itemImageURL;
    }
    public NewsFeed() {
    }

    public String getUserEmail() {
        return userEmail;
    }


    public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
    }

    public String getItemTitle() {
        return itemTitle;
    }

    public void setItemTitle(String itemTitle) {
        this.itemTitle = itemTitle;
    }

    public String getItemDescription() {
        return itemDescription;
    }

    public void setItemDescription(String itemDescription) {
        this.itemDescription = itemDescription;
    }

    public String getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(String itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }

    public String getItemPrice() {
        return itemPrice;
    }

    public void setItemPrice(String itemPrice) {
        this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
    }

    public String getItemImageURL() {
        return itemImageURL;
    }

    public void setItemImageURL(String itemImageURL) {
        this.itemImageURL = itemImageURL;
    }

    public String getItemQuantity() {
        return itemQuantity;
    }

    public void setItemQuantity(String itemQuantity) {
        this.itemQuantity = itemQuantity;
    }

    public String getItemStatus() {
        return itemStatus;
    }

    public void setItemStatus(String itemStatus) {
        this.itemStatus = itemStatus;
    }



}
```