# How to load data into an ArrayList after it's finished loading

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to load data into an ArrayList after it's finished loading ?

I am facing the same issue. Log : D/DB: []

https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/d1dyd4/androidfirebase_how_to_load_data_into_an/

How can I fix this. Thank you in advance.

```java
db.collection("fastmode")
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < QuerySnapshot > () {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < QuerySnapshot > task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot: task.getResult()) {
                    String question = documentSnapshot.getString("question");
                    String answer = documentSnapshot.getString("answer");

                    Log.d("DB", question);
                    Log.d("DB", answer);
                    questions.add(question);
                }
            }
        }
    });

Log.d("DB", String.valueOf(questions));
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FastMode.class);
startActivity( in );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your current code in a debugger and set some breakpoints, you'll see that `Log.d("DB", String.valueOf(questions))` runs before any of the `questions.add(question)`. This is because data is loaded from Firestore (and most modern cloud APIs) asynchronously.

All code that needs access to the data from the database needs to be inside the `onComplete` block. So something like:

```
db.collection("fastmode")
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < QuerySnapshot > () {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < QuerySnapshot > task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot: task.getResult()) {
                    String question = documentSnapshot.getString("question");
                    String answer = documentSnapshot.getString("answer");

                    Log.d("DB", question);
                    Log.d("DB", answer);
                    questions.add(question);
                }
                Log.d("DB", String.valueOf(questions));
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FastMode.class);
                startActivity( in );
            }
        }
    });
```

Also see:

- [How to check a certain data already exists in firestore or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000169/how-to-check-a-certain-data-already-exists-in-firestore-or-not/51002413#51002413)
- [Firebase Firestore get data from collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46706433/firebase-firestore-get-data-from-collection/46714740#46714740)